# Create a CSR with OU separated by comma instead of plus character

Tags: go, openssl, cryptography, csr, ou

I am trying to create a certificate signing request in go using the crypto lib. The problem is it generates the CSR with OU separated by `+`, i.e.

```
Subject: O = Example Org, OU = OU1 + OU = OU2, CN = example.com
```

How can I generate the CSR with OU separated by `,` like

```
Subject: O = Example Org, OU = OU1, OU = OU2, CN = example.com
```

Producing OU separated by `+` seems to be default behaviour of `crypto` lib. Can this be done using crypto lib? If no, then is there any other lib that can generate CSR with OU separated by `,`

I tried generating the CSR using below code

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    privKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    csrTemplate := x509.CertificateRequest{
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            CommonName:         "example.com",
            Organization:       []string{"Example Org"},
            OrganizationalUnit: []string{"OU1", "OU2"},
        },
        EmailAddresses: []string{"test@example.com"},
    }

    csrBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificateRequest(rand.Reader, &csrTemplate, privKey)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    csrPem := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{
        Type:  "CERTIFICATE REQUEST",
        Bytes: csrBytes,
    })

    fmt.Println(string(csrPem))
}
```

Comment: What Steffen said: you're mistaking _textual rendering_ of a CSR with the CSR itself (which is a binary in one of the encodings provided for the ASN.1 syntax: BER or DER).

Comment: The answer given by @SteffenUllrich in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77666038/create-a-csr-with-specific-subject-order-in-go/77666845#77666845) also resolves the above question. If OU field is given in extra names, it will separate the OU by , instead of +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the '+' nor the ',' are part of the certificate. It is just what is used when providing a human readable string representation of the certificate request.

In detail: your code just prints out a CSR file in PEM format, not a human readable presentation of the certificate request. Looking at this CSR with asn1parse gives:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -in csr.pem 
   ...       
   37:d=4  hl=2 l=  10 cons: SEQUENCE          
   39:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :organizationalUnitName
   44:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :OU1
   49:d=4  hl=2 l=  10 cons: SEQUENCE          
   51:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :organizationalUnitName
   56:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :OU2
   61:d=3  hl=2 l=  20 cons: SET
```

So, these are separate objects and not a combined string with a '+' between. This '+' instead comes when displaying the certificate request using req:

```
$ openssl req -in csr.pem -text 
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: O = Example Org, OU = OU1 + OU = OU2, CN = example.com
```

Which separator is used here can actually be kind of configured. See [openssl-namedisplay-options](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-namedisplay-options.html) and look for `sep_comma_plus_space`, which is the default separator. To cite the documentation:

> The first word is used between the Relative Distinguished Names (RDNs) and the second is between multiple Attribute Value Assertions (AVAs). Multiple AVAs are very rare and their use is discouraged.

So there you have it: a comma is used between different RDN (i.e. O, OU, CN, ...) while a plus is used between multiple AVA inside the same RDN (like multiple OU). Also, using multiple AVA is discouraged anyway.

Comment: Hmm...that's interesting. But then why the CSR generated by openssl command have OU's separated by ',' and CSR generated using crypto lib in go have OU's separated by '+' in human readable string representation? Do they follow some different standards or guidelines which results in different representation in human readable string?

Comment: @ShailendraKirtikar: *"... the CSR generated by openssl command ..."* - you don't show any in your question, so impossible to say what you did there. And I explained in more detail that it is not stored in the CSR at all, so there is nothing specific to golang here.