# Create a CSR with specific subject order in go

Tags: go, x509, csr

I am trying to create a certificate signing request in go using the crypto lib. The CSR produced by the has the subject as "Subject: C = IN, L = loc, O = Example Org, OU = OU1 + OU = OU2, CN = example.com". I want to change the order of the subject as "Subject: C = IN,O = Example Org, OU = OU1 + OU = OU2, L = loc, CN = example.com".

I have produced the CSR using below code.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    privKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    csrTemplate := x509.CertificateRequest{
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Country:            []string{"IN"},
            Organization:       []string{"Example Org"},
            OrganizationalUnit: []string{"OU1", "OU2"},
            Locality:           []string{"loc"},
            CommonName:         "example.com",
        },
        EmailAddresses: []string{"test@example.com"},
    }

    csrBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificateRequest(rand.Reader, &csrTemplate, privKey)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    csrPem := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{
        Type:  "CERTIFICATE REQUEST",
        Bytes: csrBytes,
    })

    fmt.Println(string(csrPem))
}
```

This code produces CSR with subject as "Subject: C = IN, L = loc, O = Example Org, OU = OU1 + OU = OU2, CN = example.com". I can generate the CSR with required subject order using openssl below command

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key my-private-key.pem -out my-csr1.pem -subj '/C=IN/O=Org/OU=OU1/OU=OU2/L=loc/CN=example.com'
```

How to do the same in go?

Comment: How is that really different from [your previous question on the same matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77660270/create-a-csr-with-ou-separated-by-comma-instead-of-plus-character)? I mean, you again appear to look at _a_ textual representation of a CSR–a representation produced by one particular piece of software,–and make sheer assumptions. Have you tried to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request), as well as general info on X.509?

Comment: May be related to issue [#52462 crypto/x509: pkix.Name.String() does not preserve correct order](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52462)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - To me, it looks like the OP is less concerned with the OUs here (which is probably also an issue) than with the order regarding L. And a related problem is addressed in the linked issue (in direct comparison to OpenSSL).

Comment: @Topaco: you are right. I assumed that based on the OPs [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77660270/create-a-csr-with-ou-separated-by-comma-instead-of-plus-character) it was about how the OU are displayed.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, I wonder is that order does _really matter_ anyway? I would assume no software to match the subject would match its individual components anyway. Is it assuption correct or wrong? (Basically, may it be that we realing with an XY problem here?)

Comment: @kostix: I would argue that software which requires a specific order here is broken. Of course, broken software exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear to me why you want to have the RDN inside the subject in this specific order. I would argue, that any software which relies on a specific order is somewhat broken. Of course, broken software exists and sometimes the only way is to work around it.

There is a way to do this using golang too. You cannot simply use the matching field names in pkix.Name though since these will be serialized in a fixed order. To get your own order you would need to use `ExtraNames` and then provide the RDN in the order you require:

```
    var (
        oidCountry            = []int{2, 5, 4, 6}
        oidOrganization       = []int{2, 5, 4, 10}
        oidOrganizationalUnit = []int{2, 5, 4, 11}
        oidCommonName         = []int{2, 5, 4, 3}
        oidLocality           = []int{2, 5, 4, 7}
    )
    csrTemplate := x509.CertificateRequest{
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            ExtraNames: []pkix.AttributeTypeAndValue{
                { oidCountry, "IN" },
                { oidOrganization, "Example Org" },
                { oidOrganizationalUnit, "OU1" },
                { oidOrganizationalUnit, "OU2" },
                { oidLocality, "loc" },
                { oidCommonName, "example.com" },
            },
        },
        EmailAddresses: []string{"test@example.com"},
    }
```

Comment: Thanks...this worked like a charm. This also solved my previous question. The OU are now somehow separated by , instead of +

Comment: @ShailendraKirtikar: *" The OU are now somehow separated by , "* - because they are added as separate RDN sequences, not as AVA in the sequence of a single RDN. But again, if your code relies on such properties then the code is likely broken. Don't make string comparison over the serialized subject string, but check the various subject elements.